# PHP Script to Insert Data From One Table To Another (Data to Large)

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a PHP script which is moving data from one table to another.

**Background**

I am merging two databases into one huge database. These databases have some similar tables, an example of this would be the `venue` table. I merged the venue tables together into the new database.

I have multiple tables which have a foreign key `venue_id` but obviously because I have merged 2 venue tables together the `venue_id`'s might be different venues now. I created this function to get the correct venue.

```
function get_tracking_venue_id($old_venue_id) {
    $db_tracking = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tracking", 'username', 'password');
    $db_tracking->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $db_intelli_sense = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=intelli_sense", 'username', 'password');
    $db_intelli_sense->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tracking_venue_table = $db_tracking->prepare("
        SELECT name FROM venue WHERE id = :venue_id
    ");
    $tracking_venue_table->bindParam(':venue_id', $old_venue_id);
    $tracking_venue_table->execute();
    $venue_name = $tracking_venue_table->fetchColumn();

    $intelli_sense_venue_table = $db_intelli_sense->prepare("
        SELECT id FROM venue WHERE name = :venue_name
    ");
    $intelli_sense_venue_table->bindParam(':venue_name', $venue_name);
    $intelli_sense_venue_table->execute();
    $venue_id = $intelli_sense_venue_table->fetchColumn();

    return $venue_id;
}
```

The function isn't the issue that just helps explain why I have had to use PHP to insert the data from one table to another which has a foreign key `venue_id`

The issue is the table I am moving to has over 3 million records. So the script keeps crashing with an out of memory error. I spent hours trying to fix this but I believe the server doesn't have enough memory.

This `fectchAll()` was causing the out of memory error

```
$fetch_summary_data = $db_tracking->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$fetch_summary_data->execute();
$tracking_summary_data_array = $fetch_summary_data->fetchAll();
```

I decided to wrap the code in a for loop which only gets 500,000 records at a time and this stopped the out of memory error. I now get this error message

```
PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=526 in /home/ubuntu/sql_scripts/tracking_wifi_merge/scripts/php_scripts/insert_tracking_daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour_script.php on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in /home/ubuntu/sql_scripts/tracking_wifi_merge/scripts/php_scripts/insert_tracking_daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour_script.php:23
```

This script takes hours to run which is why I'm getting fed up of running it and then it decides to crash halfway through. If anyone knows the reason or has a better solution to insert the data I would love to hear it.

The full script can be found below:

```
<?php

$db_tracking = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tracking", 'username', 'password');
$db_tracking->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db_intelli_sense = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=intelli_sense", 'username', 'password');
$db_intelli_sense->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/**
 * Fetch all the tracking drones
 */

$max = 1;

$get_id = $db_tracking->prepare("SELECT id FROM daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$get_id->execute();

$limit_lower  = 0;
$limit_higher = $limit_lower + 500000;

for ($count = 0; $count < $max; $count++) {
    $fetch_summary_data = $db_tracking->prepare("SELECT * FROM daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT " . $limit_lower . ", " . $limit_higher);
    $fetch_summary_data->execute();
    $tracking_summary_data_array = $fetch_summary_data->fetchAll();

    if (count($tracking_summary_data_array) != 0) {
        echo "hi";

        foreach($tracking_summary_data_array as $tracking_summary_data) {

            // Get the new venue ID
            $venue_id = get_tracking_venue_id($tracking_summary_data['venue_id']);
            if(empty($venue_id)) {
                $venue_id = 0;
            }

            /**
             * Insert the data in the zone table 
             */
            $insert_tracking_summary_data = $db_intelli_sense->prepare("
                INSERT INTO `tracking_daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour` (day_epoch, day_of_week, hour, venue_id, device_uuid, device_vendor_id, first_seen, last_seen, is_repeat)
                VALUES (:day_epoch, :day_of_week, :hour, :venue_id, :device_uuid, :device_vendor_id, :first_seen, :last_seen, :is_repeat)
            ");

            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':day_epoch', $tracking_summary_data['day_epoch']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':day_of_week', $tracking_summary_data['day_of_week']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':hour', $tracking_summary_data['hour']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':venue_id', $venue_id);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':device_uuid', $tracking_summary_data['device_uuid']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':device_vendor_id', $tracking_summary_data['device_vendor_id']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':first_seen', $tracking_summary_data['first_seen']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':last_seen', $tracking_summary_data['last_seen']);
            $insert_tracking_summary_data->bindParam(':is_repeat', $tracking_summary_data['is_repeat']);

            $insert_tracking_summary_data->execute();
        }

        $limit_lower = $limit_lower + 500001;
        $limit_higher = $limit_higher + 500000;
        $max = $max + 1;
    }
}


function get_tracking_venue_id($old_venue_id) {
    $db_tracking = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tracking", 'username', 'password');
    $db_tracking->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $db_intelli_sense = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=intelli_sense", 'username', 'password');
    $db_intelli_sense->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $tracking_venue_table = $db_tracking->prepare("
        SELECT name FROM venue WHERE id = :venue_id
    ");
    $tracking_venue_table->bindParam(':venue_id', $old_venue_id);
    $tracking_venue_table->execute();
    $venue_name = $tracking_venue_table->fetchColumn();

    $intelli_sense_venue_table = $db_intelli_sense->prepare("
        SELECT id FROM venue WHERE name = :venue_name
    ");
    $intelli_sense_venue_table->bindParam(':venue_name', $venue_name);
    $intelli_sense_venue_table->execute();
    $venue_id = $intelli_sense_venue_table->fetchColumn();

    return $venue_id;
}
```

Comment: One more thing you could try before a total rewrite. Your query `$insert_tracking_summary_data` is inside the loop, its does not need to be. Where it is will cause that to be recompiled and optimised each time round the loop. If you prepare it outside the loop you can just `bindParam()` and `execute()` it inside the loop, saving a lot of unnecessary work for the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for the advice I will let you know how to goes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The script is running but it might be about an hour before I find out there is an error. I will let you know as soon as I find out.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got an out of memory error after it inserted 1.5 million records. Im not sure why I would have gotten this error?

Comment: Was that a longer run than before?

Comment: Ok, another suggestion: You are making a new connection INSIDE the function `get_tracking_venue_id()` which also gets run every time round the loop. First connecting is slow! Second you should not need a new connection each time you call that function. Instead pass in the 2 connections you use in the main process of the script as parameters to this function.

Comment: I found an issue in my code which is why I got the memory error. The sql query where I select the limit was wrong so I changed it to ```$fetch_summary_data = $db_tracking->prepare("SELECT * FROM daily_stats_venue_unique_device_uuids_per_hour ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET " . $offset);```

Comment: I will also make your changes once the script has finished running with my code fix

Comment: I ended up stopping the query because it was taking way to long. It moved 1.5 million records with no errors so that is promising. I have now implemented the changes you suggested which will hopefully speed the query up. It started off really quick and then kept getting slower and slower. It was only inserting 20 records every second which was very slow/

Answer (score 0):

Select all data from the target database, which are required for your import and may cause errors with your foreign keys. Then create temporary tables on your source database, in which insert the selected data and add a column with the translated keys. After that, you can fetch all data from your source database in a way that it would not cause any errors in your target database. This way you can import the data way faster with much less memory. Don't do that within a transaction, so you don't have to start over if it fails.

Another way would be to create a table on your target database without constrains and for performance I would recommend the engine "MEMORY" or "MYISAM". Then import the data as it is, so without translating the constrains or everything. This should go very fast, even with multiple millions records. After that finished, run an update-command to set the foreign keys to the correct ones. Then you can move the data with a single small query. Alternatively you could write an event or set up a cron to move just a subset of data on each iteration.